# Is It More Inefficient To Serve A Zip File From Static Resouces vs Individual File?

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

If I have a zip file of javascript files and I have uploaded into static resources.  I reference a particular file inside my zip file in my VF page as follows:

`<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ZIP_FOLDER_NAME,'JS_FILES/myJsFile.js')}"></script>`

**My first question is:**
Does Salesforce directly load the individual file, or does it need to load the entire archive first and then reference my specific JS file?

**My second question is:**
Am I better of serving individual files instead of referencing a file in an archive? This also applies to my stylesheets, etc where Minifying can improve load time.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Salesforce directly load the individual file, or does it need to load the entire archive first and then reference my specific JS file?

From the browser's perspective, it receives just the file that was requested. Salesforce does have to load this file in memory, read the ZIP archive entries, then return the specific file, but this is no more complicated than how your computer handles ZIP files as a virtual folder (presuming you're using some sort of GUI). It's nearly instant, on the order of milliseconds, to retrieve the file you want.

> Am I better of serving individual files instead of referencing a file in an archive?

It makes no difference from the browser's perspective; it loads the exact same number of bytes either way. However, a ZIP file means you have fewer static resources to manage, and you can bundle everything into a nice, tidy package. This is arguably easier for the developer. And in Salesforce DX, it actually represents the files as real files in your repository, so you don't directly manage a ZIP file, either. You can even directly edit a single file and deploy the changes in near-real-time.

> This also applies to my stylesheets, etc where Minifying can improve load time.

Minification improves load time regardless of the ZIP file. Again, the browser just receives the byte-for-byte decompressed version directly from Salesforce, not a compressed or minified version; if you want the improvements that minification offers, you place those minified resources in to the ZIP.

Comment: Thank you for this information, I will go ahead and continue to utilize my resources contained as zipped files in static resources.  Appreciate the information.